# Foundation Modal with drowdown: Prevent from closing the modal

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

Hello fellows I have a modal with a dropdown:

```
Value:<span data-bind="text:value"></span><br>
<a data-bind="click:reveal" > Reveal Modal</a>



    <div data-bind="modal:showModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal >
    <a data-dropdown="drop1" aria-controls="drop1" aria-expanded="false">Has Dropdown</a>
<ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
  <li data-bind="click:duplicate">Double value</li>
  <li data-bind="click:inc">Inc value</li>
</ul>
<p>


Occaecati ut quae deleniti repudiandae corporis. Cum sed similique repellendus cum omnis. Tempora sit dolore consequatur ut quas. Enim praesentium aut a voluptatum accusantium.

Voluptatem corrupti cum ut consequatur quae eos. Eius est ad aut. Neque praesentium consequatur quisquam eum. Quos id sunt rerum. Esse eos voluptas quisquam commodi magnam. Aspernatur fugit cum nemo.

Saepe eius possimus et aut officiis. Iusto culpa aliquam asperiores ipsam. Perspiciatis ad et vero. Quos omnis asperiores qui neque aut expedita cum in. Iure ducimus minus voluptatem a. Libero ab aspernatur tempora fugit sed.

Rerum quas et quo occaecati laboriosam. Consequuntur recusandae autem vel et sed asperiores ipsum alias. Doloribus qui minus ipsam modi eveniet. Pariatur ut quisquam eius quidem ratione.

Voluptas in voluptas consectetur nihil qui qui iste. Nihil tempore eaque saepe placeat. Et eveniet dolores velit. Molestiae quia accusantium saepe est. Et earum consequatur consectetur aliquam accusamus pariatur quia. Itaque et nihil voluptatibus pariatur reprehenderit.
</p>
</div>
```

And the following html has the following js:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.modal = {
      init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(document).on('closed.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function() {
          if (this === element) {
            valueAccessor()(false);
          }
        });

        var open_binding = allBindings.get('on_modal_open') || null;
        $(document).on('open.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function() {
          if (typeof open_binding === 'function') open_binding();
        });
      },
      update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var newVal = valueAccessor()();
        if (newVal) {
          $(element).foundation('reveal', 'open');
        } else {
          $(element).foundation('reveal', 'close');
        }
      }
    };

function Reveal()
{
  var self=this;
  self.showModal=ko.observable(false);

  self.reveal=function()
  {
    self.showModal(true);
  }

  self.value=ko.observable(0);

  self.duplicate=function()
  {
    self.value(2*self.value())
  }

  self.inc=function()
  {
    self.value(self.value()+1)
  }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
  ko.applyBindings(new Reveal());
  $(document).foundation();  
})
```

And what I want is when the dropdown is oppened and I want to close it, without selecting anything, to prevent the modal to be closed/dismissed too.

How can I do that?

Note: I am Using Foundation 5.5.1 version.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWKvKm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgrated the foundation to 5.5.3 version. Later versions fix the problem